# Invariant measure for composition on space of continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $C_g:C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ be defined by $C_g(f)\triangleq f\circ g$ for some fixed $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$.

What are examples of Borel *probability* measures on $C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ which are invariant with respect to $C_g$ and are non-atomic (preferably also locally positive: ie: positive value on non-empty open subsets).

Note:  Here, $C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ is equipped with the compact-open topology; ie: uniform convergence on compacts.

Comment: I'm not sure this can have a meaningful answer in this generality. Of course it's trivial to give examples in special cases such as $g(x)=0$ or $g(x)=x+1$ (or anything that has a periodic orbit for that matter), but I suppose that's not what you wanted.

Comment: (Though I find the general case most interesting) and example which I'm also particularly curious about is the case where $g(x)=Ax+b$ and $A\in Mat_{d\times d},\, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: By the way, the extra assumptions on the measures that you added don't really rule out the trivial examples from periodic orbits (for something like $g(x)=x+1$, say) since you can take averages of measures supported by periodic orbits.

Comment: Oh, I know I just wanted to rule out examples that would be useless for me

Comment: if g is in the orthogonal group I suppose you can take any proba on R^d and average it by the compact group.

Comment: Would this give something explicit?  Also could you give some details?

Comment: Just for a nice example : Ornstein-Uhlenbeck's process for any translation $x \to x+t$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So the shift $x-> x+1$ is invariant under the law of the OU process?

Comment: I'd phrase it in a different way: the distribution of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is shift-invariant. It also satisfies your hypothesis of locality (full support in continuous functions).

Comment: @D.Thomine if you post this is more depth I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Just an idea: take $g(x) = 2x$. For any continuous $f$, the variation of $f$ on a small dyadic interval $[2^{-n}, 2^{-m}]$ goes to $0$ as $n$, $m \to + \infty$. If $f$ is random, then this variation converges almost surely, and thus in probability, to $0$. If the distribution of $f$ is $g$-invariant, then the variation of $f$ on any dyadic interval is $0$ almost surely, to $f$ is actually constant.

Comment: @D.Thomine I am confused now since the OU process' distribution is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and not on the space $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$...

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $g$ is invertible. Then everything depends on the "size" of the closed subgroup $K_g$ generated by $g$. If $K_g$ is compact, then its Haar measure and all its right convolutions are invariant with respect to the left $g$-translations. If $G$ is non-compact, then there are no probability $g$-invariant measures. I presume that a similar dichotomy should hold in the non-invertible case as well.

Comment: Isn't $\delta_c$ invariant for any constant function $c$? I think your argument only gives the non-existence of invariant probability measures on $Homeo (\mathbb{R}^d)$ (or similar groups)...

Comment: I said "Let us assume that $g$ is invertible" at the very beginning

Comment: Yes, but $f$ needs not be.

Comment: You are right - I was too much fixated on the group case. Concerning your Ornstein-Uhlenbeck example - any stationary process will actually do (either with continuous or with discrete time; in the latter case one can just interpolate between the integer time moments).